# Java Selenium - Unable to initiate multiple WebDriver with one Method

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium, fluentlenium

I have been trying for the longest time but I can't get this to work.
What I am trying to do is do load testing with Fluentlenium as a base.
When I tried to initiate my test, it only open one chrome browser and in my IDE, the same method is running 3x (for example) Sometimes the test passes and sometimes it fails. Its suppose to be launching 3 chrome browser under different port (generated by selenium) but it doesn't, it only launch 1 browser.

Here's my code that's failing:

```
    public class Example extends FluentTestNg {
        private final static String DEFAULT_URL = "http://google.com";

        @Override
        public WebDriver newWebDriver() {
            DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(caps);
            return driver;
        }


        @Test(invocationCount = 3, threadPoolSize = 3)
        public void GoogleTest() throws Exception {
            goTo(DEFAULT_URL);
            await().until($(".gsfi")).present();
            System.out.println(getCookies());
        }
    }
```

Heres the stacktrace that was provide that it failed

```
    Starting ChromeDriver 2.30.477690 (c53f4ad87510ee97b5c3425a14c0e79780cdf262) on port 14851
Only local connections are allowed.
Jun 19, 2017 12:53:03 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Jun 19, 2017 12:53:03 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute

INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {}->http://localhost:14851: Broken pipe (Write failed)
Jun 19, 2017 12:53:03 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {}->http://localhost:14851

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: no such session
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477690 (c53f4ad87510ee97b5c3425a14c0e79780cdf262),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.5 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 59 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.3.1', revision: '5234b325d5', time: '2017-03-10 09:10:29 +0000'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.30.477690 (c53f4ad87510ee97b5c3425a14c0e79780cdf262), userDataDir=/var/folders/1j/tdgn9dcn6d9g9dcd3fs8nj8c0000gn/T/.org.chromium.Chromium.yRHaZe}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=59.0.3071.86, platform=MAC, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
Session ID: 25c29b733c90f9dff2afb69dee6dc1d5

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:638)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:274)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.isEnabled(RemoteWebElement.java:148)
    at org.fluentlenium.core.proxy.ComponentHandler.isStale(ComponentHandler.java:52)
    at org.fluentlenium.core.proxy.AbstractLocatorHandler.present(AbstractLocatorHandler.java:225)
    at org.fluentlenium.core.proxy.LocatorProxies.present(LocatorProxies.java:113)
    at org.fluentlenium.core.domain.FluentWebElement.present(FluentWebElement.java:132)
    at org.fluentlenium.core.conditions.AbstractObjectConditions.verify(AbstractObjectConditions.java:36)
    at org.fluentlenium.core.conditions.WebElementConditions.present(WebElementConditions.java:43)
    at org.fluentlenium.core.conditions.AbstractFluentListConditions.lambda$present$0(AbstractFluentListConditions.java:79)
    at org.fluentlenium.core.conditions.AtLeastOneElementConditions.lambda$buildAtLeastOnePredicate$0(AtLeastOneElementConditions.java:49)
    at org.fluentlenium.core.conditions.AtLeastOneElementConditions.verify(AtLeastOneElementConditions.java:35)
    at org.fluentlenium.core.conditions.AbstractFluentListConditions.present(AbstractFluentListConditions.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.fluentlenium.core.conditions.wait.WaitConditionInvocationHandler$2.apply(WaitConditionInvocationHandler.java:216)
    at org.fluentlenium.core.conditions.wait.WaitConditionInvocationHandler$2.apply(WaitConditionInvocationHandler.java:212)
    at org.fluentlenium.core.conditions.wait.WaitConditionInvocationHandler.lambda$until$0(WaitConditionInvocationHandler.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:209)
    at org.fluentlenium.core.wait.FluentWait.untilPredicate(FluentWait.java:131)
    at org.fluentlenium.core.conditions.wait.WaitConditionInvocationHandler.until(WaitConditionInvocationHandler.java:144)
    at org.fluentlenium.core.conditions.wait.WaitConditionInvocationHandler.until(WaitConditionInvocationHandler.java:175)
    at org.fluentlenium.core.conditions.wait.WaitConditionInvocationHandler.waitForCondition(WaitConditionInvocationHandler.java:212)
    at org.fluentlenium.core.conditions.wait.WaitConditionInvocationHandler.invoke(WaitConditionInvocationHandler.java:190)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.present(Unknown Source)
    at Example.GoogleTest(Example.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:643)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:820)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1128)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil$2.call(ThreadUtil.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: Elements By.cssSelector: .gsfi (Lazy Element List) is not present (tried for 5 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)
Build info: version: '3.3.1', revision: '5234b325d5', time: '2017-03-10 09:10:29 +0000'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown

    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.timeoutException(FluentWait.java:264)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:232)
    at org.fluentlenium.core.wait.FluentWait.untilPredicate(FluentWait.java:131)
    at org.fluentlenium.core.conditions.wait.WaitConditionInvocationHandler.until(WaitConditionInvocationHandler.java:144)
    at org.fluentlenium.core.conditions.wait.WaitConditionInvocationHandler.until(WaitConditionInvocationHandler.java:175)
    at org.fluentlenium.core.conditions.wait.WaitConditionInvocationHandler.waitForCondition(WaitConditionInvocationHandler.java:212)
    at org.fluentlenium.core.conditions.wait.WaitConditionInvocationHandler.invoke(WaitConditionInvocationHandler.java:190)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.present(Unknown Source)
    at Example.GoogleTest(Example.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:643)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:820)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1128)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil$2.call(ThreadUtil.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have another method that works fine but I have to pass newWebDriver method for it to work...

```
public class Example extends FluentTestNg {
    private final static String DEFAULT_URL = "http://google.com";

    private static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> drivers = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>();

    public void setWebdriver(WebDriver driver){
        drivers.set(driver);
    }

    @Override
    public WebDriver newWebDriver() {
        return drivers.get ();
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void launchbrowser(){
        WebDriver drivers = new ChromeDriver();
        setWebdriver(drivers);
    }


    @Test(invocationCount = 3, threadPoolSize = 3)
    public void GoogleTest() throws Exception {
        newWebDriver().get(DEFAULT_URL);
    }
}
```

Heres the console log of it passing with 3 browsers opening but I can't use Fluentlenium syntax.

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.30.477690 (c53f4ad87510ee97b5c3425a14c0e79780cdf262) on port 11700
Only local connections are allowed.
Starting ChromeDriver 2.30.477690 (c53f4ad87510ee97b5c3425a14c0e79780cdf262) on port 35621
Only local connections are allowed.
Starting ChromeDriver 2.30.477690 (c53f4ad87510ee97b5c3425a14c0e79780cdf262) on port 31113
Only local connections are allowed.
Jun 19, 2017 12:59:11 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Jun 19, 2017 12:59:11 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Jun 19, 2017 12:59:11 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
```

The only problem is, I can't use the built in Fluentlenium syntax to it (exp: GoTo,GetCookies, Await, ect.). I have to use Selenium syntax.

Is there any way to get this to work with just Fluentlenium?

Comment: First thing that might be confusing you is your `drivers` variable names. As far as I can tell, you're never storing a collection of `drivers`, so change all of that to `driver`. Second, since you want to have a bunch of instances running at once, you probably shouldn't be storing your `WebDriver` in a static variable. Hope that helps a bit :)

Comment: Although, if you're using ThreadLocal maybe all you need to do is make your get method static... IE `public static WebDriver newWebDriver() `. You might want to change that method name to `getDriver` or `getCurrentDriver` since it's not creating a new one as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could try getting rid of ThreadLocal and making you WebDriver not static. Or with your current code it might be as simple as making sure your `get` method for your `ThreadLocal` field is `static`:

```
public static WebDriver newWebDriver() {
    return drivers.get ();
}
```

I noticed your overriding this `newWebDriver` method from somewhere, I'm not totally clear if that's actually what you want to be doing here since I don't know where that is coming from.